# C++ using threads in a for loop

Tags: c++, realsense

What is different about this code:

```
std::vector<Server> realsense_server_arr;
for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
    printf("Initializing server... %d\n", i);
    Server realsense_server(50000 + i);
    realsense_server.init_listener_thread();
    realsense_server_arr.emplace_back(realsense_server);
}
int depth_size = aligned_depth.get_width() * aligned_depth.get_height() * aligned_depth.get_bytes_per_pixel();
realsense_server_arr[0].update_buffer((unsigned char*)aligned_depth.get_data(), 10 * 4, depth_size);
int color_size = data.get_color_frame().get_width() * data.get_color_frame().get_height() * data.get_color_frame().get_bytes_per_pixel();
realsense_server_arr[0].update_buffer((unsigned char*)color.get_data(), 10*4 + depth_size, color_size);

// Send camera intrinsics and depth scale
realsense_server_arr[0].update_buffer((unsigned char*)color_intrinsics_arr, 0, 9 * 4);
realsense_server_arr[0].update_buffer((unsigned char*)&depth_scale, 9 * 4, 4);
```

versus this code:

```
Server realsense_server(50000);
realsense_server.init_listener_thread();

int depth_size = aligned_depth.get_width() * aligned_depth.get_height() * aligned_depth.get_bytes_per_pixel();
realsense_server.update_buffer((unsigned char*)aligned_depth.get_data(), 10 * 4, depth_size);

int color_size = data.get_color_frame().get_width() * data.get_color_frame().get_height() * data.get_color_frame().get_bytes_per_pixel();
realsense_server.update_buffer((unsigned char*)color.get_data(), 10 * 4 + depth_size, color_size);

// Send camera intrinsics and depth scale
realsense_server.update_buffer((unsigned char*)color_intrinsics_arr, 0, 9 * 4);
realsense_server.update_buffer((unsigned char*)&depth_scale, 9 * 4, 4);
```

They are functionally the same (I think?).

The first code creates an array, adds a Server object, and updates the buffer based on the 0 array index. Since i<1, the array is length 1.

The second code does the same without an array.

Is there some issue with accessing threaded objects in an array like this?

Server code is here: https://github.com/andyzeng/visual-pushing-grasping/blob/580e2334beec0d83b49e6ca89d7542b79d1d4350/realsense/realsense.cpp#L24

The first code fails to create the TCP server correctly, it does not respond to messages and hangs. The second code succeeds.

Comment: There is a copy operation in emplace_back. You may want to initialize Server when "emplacing" it and then run realsense_server_arr.back().init_listener_thread();

Comment: You should put the server's code here, since the link might become obsolete and your question will be useless for other users.

Comment: @AdrielJr That is amazing that you caught it. That was exactly the problem. It seems like I can't get away with trying to jump from being an expert python programmer to a good C++ programmer... lots of intricacies like this that probably can't be learned without reading entirely through a C++ book

Comment: @AdrielJr However one problem is, after I make the change you suggested, if I change "i < 1" back to "i < 3", it segfaults... what gives?

Answer (score 1):

The former of these make a copy of `realsense_server`, placing that copy into the vector, and acting exclusively on that copy thereafter. The state of that copy can (and by the looks of it is) considerably different than the concrete object from whence it was copied. Equally important, that concrete object `realsense_server` is *destroyed* upon leaving the for-loop iteration.

I won't even begin to suggest I know the first thing about the library you're using, but I will suggest you would have better success with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
    printf("Initializing server... %d\n", i);
    realsense_server_arr.emplace_back(50000 + i);
    realsense_server_arr.last().init_listener_thread();
}
```

This will create the object in-place at the tail of the vector, and initialize the listener thread of *that* object directly. If the limit of `i` is known and greater than `1` (I would hope it is, otherwise this is mostly pointless) you likely want to reserve the vector capacity first. I.e.,

```
std::vector<Server> realsense_server_arr;
realsense_server_arr.reserve(n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("Initializing server... %d\n", i);
    realsense_server_arr.emplace_back(50000 + i);
    realsense_server_arr.last().init_listener_thread();
}
```

Comment: One problem is, after I make the change you suggested, if I change "i < 1" back to "i < 3", it segfaults... what gives?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. As I said, I'm not a RealSense guy, just a C++ guy. A debugger could probably point you to the problem quickly, however. The code above in this answer should be sound, however.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the server code or the TCP code